# how much gravity were Trunks and Vegeta training in, when they trained together before the martial arts tournament?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

When Trunks was training with Vegeta before the martial arts tournament where he fought against Goten, how much gravity were they training under? In the spanish dub it says 150,000 times gravity. In the english dub it says 150 times gravity. I have no idea if the spanish dub was a mistake, or the english dub was a mistake. What does the original japanese dialogue says, if it says something at all?

Comment: It is obviously 150 times because even Vegeta didn't go beyond 500 times gravity and the same 150 times repeated in DBZ Kai 104 episode.

Comment: May be it is 150 times but 150,000 times makes more sense in the storyline. Perhaps that's why they changed in the spanish dub if the spanish version is incorrect. Goku trained under 100 times gravity when he had a power level of 90,000 and by that time Vegeta is thousands of times stronger than 90,000, so one would expect he trains under a thousands of times stronger gravity

Comment: I don't think so Vegeta has tough time with Captain ginu hench man in starting but Goku easily defeated​ them

Comment: By the time Vegeta is training in the gravity chamber with Trunks, which is like 12 years later of that event. Vegeta is already a Super Saiyan for at least 10 years

Comment: But the kid trunks is a child and he is a human when entered into gravity room but he is half sayain though but as human his power level is 50 times less in base form hence cannot with stand 150,000 gravity

Answer (score 1):

I think it's 150 only If you aren't​ satisfied let us do some math if kid trunks is about 20 kg then he would weight 20*150*10=30000N which is 3tons(3000kg) in normal gravity if he is at 150,000 times gravity then kid trunks would weight 20*150,000*10=30000000 which is 3000tons remember Goku training with king Kai in other world he say that 4 tons is too much for base form and too light for super Saiyan form hence​ 150 is reasonable

Comment: well, it's always been argued that Goku in that scene never made sense. If Goku is 80 kgs, when he's training under 100 times gravity in a period of the timeline where he is hundreds of times less stronger he would be 8 tons under which he trains with no problem . By that time Goku is 90,000 in base form. By the time he couldnt train under 4 tons he's probably around 100,000,000 or so in base form, and supposedly he couldnt train under half the weight he could when he was 1000 less stronger. Some people speculates to fix the plothole that place where Goku is training is under more gravity